# Google contacts missing on Android

Tags: contacts, sync, google, google-calendar

I originally solved a calendar sync problem using a post in the forum by deleting Google account and then adding. The calendar sync worked, but I realized I was missing all of my google contacts. After trying some things I still have no contacts (have restored them on my laptop so they are showing there) and now I have a sync error on both contacts and again in calendar with nothing showing in either.